# My VBA to change a folder name isn't quite right, what am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put in some VBA that checks if a folder name should be changed based on whether something in the record has been changed (i.e. the folder was initially opened with a spelling mistake or similar).

The current name of the folder is fixed in cell B51 on a background sheet as soon as a user opens the form to update anything (and before they actually do any updating).  A formula in B52 shows how the folder would be named based on whatever they've updated.  So, if the two differ, it means the folder name needs to be changed to the new one.

Here's what i have;

```
Dim strOldDirName As String
Dim strNewDirName As String

strOldDirName = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B51").Value
strNewDirName = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B52").Value

If strOldDirName <> strNewDirName Then
Name strOldDirName As strNewDirName
Else
End If
```

All of the updates that the user makes are stored in some other code and it all works great, apart from the folder name is not changing.

strOldDirName and strNewDirName are full file paths including folder name.  I'm wondering if the folder name need to be defined separately to the file path - Could that be why it's not updating the folder name or am I missing something else?

EDIT - here is screenshot of the old and new paths - the change being that a persons name has been added to the folder name instead of it being '0' (picture added to redact company name from the path!)

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to rename the folder in which your excel file is located this won't work because Windows will not let you rename a folder that contains an open file.

Comment: If you step through with F8 are the 2 path variables populated 100% correctly if you hover your mouse over them? Does the folder to replace actually exist? Do you have errors suppressed in this code? If so, is there anything open in the replacing folder or are there illegal characters in folder name etc...

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The file I'm using isn't based in the folder I'm trying to change.  The folder in it's current form definitely exists, I can copy/paste in to File Explorer and go straight in to it.  There's also no errors coming out from stepping through.  The file paths aren't links as such, the current one is text and the one to rename it as is a formula.

Comment: What error do you get? If no error then do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No errors at all, the rest of the code executes perfectly and it runs through this part of the code, it jsut doesn't change the folder name!  No On Error Resume Next in there at all.

Comment: Have a try doing it without the variables and put the paths directly into the name function just to see if it works. Eg `Name "C:\..." As "C:\...."`

Comment: good shout, will have a pop at that now, thanks

Comment: Oh wait your trying to change a folder name but have a file included at the end? To change the folder name you need it to be `C:\FolderToChange` not `C:\FolderToChange\File.txt`. If that's the case I'm surprised your not getting an error.

Comment: If `strNewDirName` already exists you cannot change anything. But you should receive an error.

Comment: Sort of, but there's no file at the end.  An example of an 'old' path is this, where the sinal part of the path is the folder name -  `C:\Users\townej02\***\OGRP-B&Q Security & Risk Prevention - Documents\Fraud And Risk Manager\Cases\2021-1 (0 - HEN222)`

Comment: Another intricacy is that users access it through OneDrive so the username part of the file path varies depending on who's using it, making it a bit more challenging to put the path directly in to the code!

Comment: I am afraid that it is possible to have a UDV function, an event, something else using `On Error Resume Next`, without being followed by `On Error GoTo 0`. I would try inserting a line just before the naming row `Set sh = Worksheets("VVVVVVV")`, which not exist. Does your code raise an error?. If yes, how many characters are in the paths you use?

Comment: That code did error.  There are 132 characters in the whole file path!

Comment: And did putting the path in directly work or did it not?

Comment: Just finished that - unfortunately not.  There's an issue with having the path coded in as the username changes and is part of the file path itself (OneDrive...)

Comment: But, if the path si wrong, **it should raise an error stating that**! Are you sure that the folder name does not change? Did you try refreshing the folder keeping it? In fact, if this is happening, next time you try it will warn that the folder has not been found. Very strange...

Comment: The path will be right as it's my username on my machine, so there's no error.  The formula that works out the new path has a step in it that defines the username, so the path will be correct for everyone using it.  The old folder is still named as the old folder, it's definitely not changed to the new name!

Comment: I've just added an image of the file paths that are in B51 and B52 to the original post (needed to use an image so i can redact the company name :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're not sure about what is the problem. Maybe have a go using `FileSystemObject` to rename rather than the `Name` function.

This should grab the last folder name (by searching for the last `\` symbol in the path and extracting what's right of it. See if this works.

Edit: I forgot about the check. I would put it before changing the `strNewDirName` variable.

```
Dim strOldDirName As String
Dim strNewDirName As String

strOldDirName = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B51").Value
strNewDirName = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B52").Value

If strOldDirName <> strNewDirName Then
    strNewDirName = Right(strNewDirName, Len(strNewDirName) - InStrRev(strNewDirName, "\"))

    Dim FSO As Object, FSOFolder As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSOFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strOldDirName)

    FSOFolder.Name = strNewDirName

End If
```

Comment: Thanks Simon.  That bombs out at the final point 'FSOFolder.Name = strNewDirName' though

Comment: Could it be anything to do with strNewDirName being a formula rather than text?

Comment: You added the line to refine strNewDirName right? If you step through what do you get for `strNewDirName` once it's refined? It should just be the actual folder name that's on the end. AKA `2020-21 (DAVE - HEN222)`

Comment: It's showing the correct folder name when I step through, but the error I'm getting at the final stage is 'Error 5. folder name already exists'!  It's almost as if it's finding that it should change from 'DAVE' to 'BOB' (or whoever) and then trying to change it to what it already is!?

Comment: @John Townend: This only means that the folder has changed its name (using your code or running the above one twice)...

Comment: So, I changed it from 'DAVE' to 'BOB', stepped through and it's changed the folder name perfectly.  Changed it from 'BOB' to 'SIMON' (a little homage ;)) and it's bombing out again saying the folder already exists, but the folder is still called BOB!

Comment: You changed both old and new in the cells when doing that? (B51 and B52)

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it!  @Simon's answer was absolutely spot on, but I had overwritten the part of the code that checked if strOldDirName was <> strNewDirName so it was constantly trying to change something that didn't need changing.

I've added that back in and run it a few times and the folder name changes perfectly each time.

Thank you so, so much for your help, you're life savers!